# Is it correct to use 'should' in the second conditional main clause?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Context:

> I have a toothache. I don't have any chocolate.

I wonder if it's correct to say:

> Even if I had chocolate, I shouldn't eat it.

The problem is the main clause doesn't change in the first and second conditionals here:

> Even if I have chocolate, I shouldn't eat it.

Comment: Used in the sense of expressing appropriateness (and also in the sense of expressing probability!) _shouldn't_ makes sense here, and it is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Mori are you asking because it sounds wrong to you? If so, can you explain why it sounds wrong? Or if not, please list the 'rules' you're trying to understand, and explain what you find vague or difficult to understand about those 'rules' regarding whether "should" can be used.

Comment: @Lawrence: The problem is the main clause doesn't change in the first and second conditionals here, i.e. "Even if I have chocolate, I shouldn't eat it."

Comment: @Mori Ah, that would be an excellent point to [edit] into your question. It gets to the heart of the matter, and would help the community direct their efforts towards a more satisfying answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but the second one is rather strange:

> Even if I have chocolate, I shouldn't eat it.

You presumably know whether you have chocolate or not! If you do have chocolate, then it is better to say

> Even though I have chocolate, I shouldn't eat it.

If you don't have chocolate, then the conditional version is better:

> Even if I had chocolate, I shouldn't eat it.

Answer (score 0):

While *to have* typically means "to possess" among other things, it can also have an implication of "to obtain" or "to get," especially with food.

> Have some soup. (Go get some soup.)
>
> We're having dinner, why are you calling me?

So with this:

> Even if I had chocolate, I shouldn't eat it.

The logic here is that you got chocolate in the past, and still have it now, so it's correct to use present tense in "I shouldn't eat it."

Comment: I'm sure this is wrong. "Even if I had chocolate" is present conditional, not simple past.